# Is there a tool to check GPOs like MBSA?

Tags: security, group-policy, configuration-management

I'd like to provide some background before I pose my question so please, bear with me.

I have come across Microsoft's Security Compliance Manager. It's rather new to me and as I understand so far, one can download EC (enterprise) or SSLF (specialized security, limited function) security "baseline" GPOs for implementation in Active Directory. The baselines are for XP, Win 7, Win 2k3, and 2k8.

GPOAccelerator can deploy or implement these baseline GPOs for a Domain or Locally.

I believe SCCM's DCM can compare GPOs that one has created against GPOs from the SCM?

And now for my question: Is there a tool to check GPOs like MBSA? 
Bonus: Is there any tool that will give a security rating for "missing" GPOs or "weak" GPOs?

Comment: Wow. Too many acronyms for me. You lost me halfway, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what OS's you are actually running, but the Group Policy Diagnostic BPA for Server 2003 (here - http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=47F11B02-8EE4-450B-BF13-880B91BA4566&displaylang=en) might be what you are looking for.  They also have a version that runs on XP.

I don't know if there is a tool yet for Server 08 and Vista and beyond.